# Как задать собственное изображение в качестве значка для всех меток на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

На карту добавлены несколько меток, нужно для всех задать иконку в виде моего изображения. Точки добавлены в кластер.
Как это сделать?

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [57.920669, 59.975301],
      zoom: 11
    }),
    // Создадим массив геообъектов.
    myGeoObjects = [];
  myGeoObjects[0] = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [57.907594, 59.969703]
    },
    properties: {
      clusterCaption: 'Текст',
      balloonContentHeader: "<b>Текст</b>",
      balloonContentBody: '<br><p>Текст</p>',
      hintContent: "Текст"
    }
  });

  myGeoObjects[1] = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [57.906252, 59.955023]
    },
    properties: {
      clusterCaption: 'Текст',
      balloonContentHeader: "<b>Текст</b>",
      balloonContentBody: '<br><p>Текст</p>',
      hintContent: "Текст"
    }
  });

  // Создадим кластеризатор и запретим приближать карту при клике на кластеры.
  var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
    clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
    clusterBalloonContentLayoutWidth: 450,
    clusterBalloonContentLayoutHeight: 350,
    geoObjectBalloonContentLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div style="background-color: red">{{ properties.balloonContentBody|raw }}</div>')
  })
  clusterer.add(myGeoObjects);
  map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
  map.geoObjects.options.set('balloonMinWidth', 800);

}
```

```css
</style><script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script><style>html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: #04b;
  /* Цвет ссылки */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Убираем подчеркивание у ссылок */
}

a:visited {
  color: #04b;
  /* Цвет посещённой ссылки */
}

a:hover {
  color: #f50000;
  /* Цвет ссылки при наведении на нее курсора мыши */
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пресет в виде изображения сразу всем меткам на карте можно задать через опции геообъектов карты:

```
map.geoObjects.options.set('iconLayout','default#image');
map.geoObjects.options.set('iconImageHref','https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/icon_customImage/images/ball.png')
```

[Вот интерактивный пример](https://jsfiddle.net/kkc85q9f/)